# Color management of a toggle button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script>
        function setColor(btn,color){
            var property=document.getElementById(btn);
            if (window.getComputedStyle(property).backgroundColor == 'rgb(244, 113, 33)') {
                property.style.backgroundColor=color;
            } else {
                property.style.backgroundColor = "#33FF00";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btnHousing" value="In" onclick="setColor('btnHousing','#fff200');" />
    <input type="button" id="btnHousing2" value="Out" onclick="setColor('btnHousing2','#fff200');" />
</body>
</html>
```

What i would like to happen is that when I will press the button 'In', I would like to make it green, and If I will press the 'Out' button, It will also be green but the 'In' button will go back to its original color. I would like to make it like a toggle button. How?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only changing the background color of `property` (the current button), given that its background color is not `rgb(244, 113, 33)` (a shade of orange). Considering the background color is only ever green or yellow, only the `else` part is ever executed, and only for the current button.

I am unsure where `rgb(244, 113, 33)` comes from, but given that you want to toggle the buttons between green and yellow (`#33FF00` and `#fff200`), the following solution works.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="btnHousing" value="In" onclick="setColor(this)">
<input type="button" id="btnHousing2" value="Out" onclick="setColor(this)">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function setColor (obj) {
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btnHousing'),
        btn2 = document.getElementById('btnHousing2');

    // Reset both backgrounds.
    btn1.style.backgroundColor = btn2.style.backgroundColor = '#fff200';

    // Change the current background to green.
    obj.style.backgroundColor = '#33FF00';
}
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/eCAcOFIY/1/